# Why tailwind css is not shown in the DevTools?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, devtools

Using Chrome's DevTools, I look at an element like `<div class="w-10"></div>` and I see this in styles tab:

[image]

But when I click on the `styles.css:3`, I don't see the CSS class and properties, all I see is my original CSS content:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Why does it work like that? What new knowledge do I miss that I don't understand this?

Comment: You should be able to inspect the style sheet in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind removed all classes to be load at initial. It loads css into our app when we add it in our application. In order to view all classes simple add below one

tailwind.config.js - Add safelist - will make magic for you

export default {
content: [
"./index.html",
"./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
],
**safelist: [
{
pattern: /.*/
}
]**,
theme: {
extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
}

Answer (score -1):

Actually, "w-10" (and all other pre-defined tailwind classes) are termed as tailwind utility. And all these tailwind classes are saved in this utility layer of tailwindcss (that's the working mechanism of tailwind as it also has these tailwind classes assigned corresponding css properties in order to save us from writing long css). That's what it is exactly pointing towards.